# Google Cloud Dataflow how to reduce size of http_request

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow job that seems to be failing due to an overly large http_request body sent when attempting to create the job. This is the request header:

```
{'content-length': '107245818', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'accept': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'x_xxxxxxxx'}
```

Sending the request gives me:

```
413. That's an error.

Your client issued a request that was too large.
```

What's getting put into the request body that makes it so large? What can I do to reduce its size or get Google's servers to accept the request?

I'm using the Apache Beam Python SDK version 2.4.0.

Comment: This means that the JSON representation of your job is too large ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#413-request-entity-too-large--the-size-of-serialized-json-representation------of-the-pipeline-exceeds-the-allowable-limit)) and needs to be optimized (hard to know without code). Maximum is 10 MB and you seem to be slightly over it. Use `--dataflow_job_file=< path to output file >` to check it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the serialized function definition through [pickletools.dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickletools.html) to see what was taking up so much space. It seems to be due entirely to a `CombineFn`'s `extract_output` definition.

Going from:

```
def extract_output(self, accumulator):
    output = zip(self.id_list, accumulator[1], *accumulator[0])
    return output
```

to

```
def extract_output(self, accumulator):
    return accumulator
```

brings `content-length` from `'74538844'` to `'858884'` about a factor of 100 times less.

`accumulator` holds two numpy arrrays with dimensions `len(id_list) x len(id_list)` and `len(id_list)`. `id_list` provides integer labels (roughly 3000 in this case) for each row of the arrays and is known when constructing the pipeline.

I don't know why this happens, but keying with ID in a DoFn after the CombineFn generates a reasonably sized request and produces roughly the same output.